# Closing over java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap inside a Future of Actor's receive method?

Tags: performance, scala, thread-safety, akka, concurrenthashmap

I've an actor where I want to store my mutable state inside a map.

Clients can send `Get(key:String)` and `Put(key:String,value:String)` messages to this actor.

I'm considering the following options.

1. Don't use futures inside the Actor's receive method. In this may have a negative impact on both latency as well as throughput in case I've a large number of `gets/puts` because all operations will be performed in order.
2. Use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` and then invoke the gets and puts inside a `Future`.

Given that `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe and providers finer level of granularity, I was wondering if it is still a problem to close over the concurrentHashMap inside a Future created for each put and get.

I'm aware of the fact that it's a really bad idea to *close* over mutable state inside  a Future inside an Actor but I'm still interested to know if in this particular case it is correct or not?

Comment: Why do you have futures in this case? Does the `HashMap` live outside your actor? If everything is inside your actor then there is no need for using futures. In that case you don't need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` either - plain old `Map` would do just fine.

Comment: @CemCatikkas - According to the semantics of the actor model, the messages in the actor's mailbox will be processed in order. This also means that unless a message is completely processed, the next message will have to wait. For example, imagine if you have 100s of messages that read from a mutable map inside the Actor. On a multicore machine you should be able to read these concurrently. Using Futures is one way of doing this.

Comment: Accessing this hashmap is an in-memory operation. Wrapping it in a future adds overhead and will probably be an overkill. Unless if you have a legitimate reason to use a future in this scenario you shouldn't. That said you should really measure and then determine what the best use for your case will be.

Comment: @CemCatikkas - I agree with both points. Pushing it on a Future _may_ be more expensive. I'll try to do some measurements.

Comment: It's safe but still against best practices. You could get the same parellelism with a routing actor that forwarded to a pool of Get/Set actors, analagous to ConcurrentHashmap's striping across a set of locks.  If this actually improves performance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is made for concurrent use.  As long as you don't try to transport the closure to another machine, and you think through the implications of it being used concurrently (e.g. if you read a value, use a function to modify it, and then put it back, do you want to use the `replace(key, oldValue, newValue)` method to make sure it hasn't changed while you were doing the processing?), it should be fine in Futures.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little late, but still, in the book [Reactive Web Applications](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-web-applications), the author has indicated an indirection to this specific problem, using pipeTo as below.

```
def receive = {
  case ComputeReach(tweetId) =>
    fetchRetweets(tweetId, sender()) pipeTo self
  case fetchedRetweets: FetchedRetweets =>
    followerCountsByRetweet += fetchedRetweets -> List.empty
    fetchedRetweets.retweets.foreach { rt =>
      userFollowersCounter ! FetchFollowerCount(
       fetchedRetweets.tweetId, rt.user
    )
}
...
}
```

where `followerCountsByRetweet` is a mutable state of the actor. The result of `fetchRetweets()` which is a Future is piped to the same actor as a `FetchedRetweets` message, which then acts on the message on to modify the state of the acto., this will mitigate any concurrent operation on the state